# Google appengine using appcfg from behind proxy with authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, windows-xp

Im working behind a corporate proxy and was fine while i was using the eclipse plugin configured with my proxy credentials. Then one of my deployments failed and now I have to rollback my previous transaction. Im trying to use appcfg (either .py or .cmd) since I think that is the only way to rollback. Im getting either timouts or proxy authentication errors when i set the proxy. setting an environment variable to http_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.com doesnt seem to work. also im on windows xp.

does anyone have any ideas as to how to rollback without using appcfg or how to set appcfg to use a proxy with authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access the admin console from behind the firewall?  You can set the current version there.  There is a "Versions" link on the left hand side of the admin console, under the "Administration" heading.  It will allow you to set the "Default" version.

Comment: ok so changing the version when I deploy did work, but I wonder if there isnt an open transaction still for the previous version.

Comment: could be. i've reached the end of my knowledge at this point though :)